# Why does mempty evaluate the content of the Monoid

Tags: haskell, monoids

Why does

```
(mempty :: String)
```

work, but

```
(mempty :: Maybe Bool)
```

gives me an error about `Bool` not having a type class of `Monoid`, but why does it even matter, it's wrapped in Maybe anyway?

Comment: The behavior you are (probably) thinking of is encoded in [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative). `empty :: Maybe Bool` is `Nothing` and `(<|>)` takes the first non-`Nothing` value.

Answer (score 6):

For lists, `[a]` is a `Monoid` [no matter what](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-240):

```
instance {- no requirements on a here! => -} Monoid [a] where
    ...
```

So `String` is a monoid without further inspection of the properties of `Char`. But `Maybe a` is [only an instance of `Monoid` if `a` is](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-314):

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a) where
    ...
```

So for `Maybe Bool` to be a monoid, we must check that `Bool` is a monoid. This fully explains your error message.

Followup question number one: why does `a` need to be a `Monoid`? That is so that we can write `mappend`:

```
    Just m1 `mappend` Just m2 = Just (m1 `mappend` m2)
```

Of course, you really only need `Semigroup` for that; but this subtle difference is irrelevant because `Bool` isn't a `Semigroup`, either.

Followup question number two: why isn't `Bool` a `Monoid`? Because there are several good instances, and it's not clear which to "bless" as the official instance. So the instances are attached to `newtype`s over `Bool`; the two most common are [`Any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Any) and [`All`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:All).

Followup question number three: what are your alternatives? You might like [`First`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) or [`Last`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Last) for the monoids that keep the first (resp. last) `Just` they see. There is also the standard instance and an instance where `mempty = pure mempty; mappend = liftA2 mappend` though I don't know a standard place for this.

Comment: @Tarmil (For completeness, the other two monoids on `Bool` are `(/=)/False` and `(==)/True`, which are basically `Sum Word1` with the two possible representations of `Word1` as `Bool`.)

Comment: These are also called the XOR and XNOR monoids, for obvious reasons. (Obvious if you know what XOR and XNOR are, at least.)

Answer (score 4):

This is the [`Monoid` instance for `Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-314):

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a) where
  mempty = Nothing
  Nothing `mappend` m = m
  m `mappend` Nothing = m
  Just m1 `mappend` Just m2 = Just (m1 `mappend` m2)
```

It requires the underlying type to have a `Monoid` instance because its own `mappend` delegates to that of the underlying type. Note that this `Monoid` constraint is unnecessarily restrictive, as the underlying `mempty` isn't actually used. A more appropriate take on that is provided as [`Option` in `Data.Semigroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Option) (a `Semigroup` is a `Monoid` without `mempty`):

```
-- Paraphrasing the relevant bits of the source.
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a) where
  Nothing <> b       = b
  a       <> Nothing = a
  Just a  <> Just b  = Just (a <> b)

newtype Option a = Option { getOption :: Maybe a }

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Option a) where
  Option ma <> Option mb = Option (ma <> mb)

instance Semigroup a => Monoid (Option a) where
  mempty = Option Nothing
  mappend = (<>)
```

If you want a `Monoid` for `Maybe` that doesn't care about the underlying type, have a look at the newtype wrappers provided by `Data.Monoid`: [`First`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) (or `Alt Maybe`) for the left-biased one and [`Last`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Last) (or `Dual (Alt Maybe)`) for the right-biased one.

```
-- For instance, this is the First monoid:
newtype First a = First { getFirst :: Maybe a }

instance Monoid (First a) where
        mempty = First Nothing
        First Nothing `mappend` r = r
        l `mappend` _             = l
```

```
GHCi> import Data.Monoid
GHCi> First Nothing <> First Nothing
First {getFirst = Nothing}
GHCi> First (Just 3) <> First Nothing
First {getFirst = Just 3}
GHCi> First Nothing <> First (Just 3)
First {getFirst = Just 3}
GHCi> First (Just 3) <> First (Just 4)
First {getFirst = Just 3}
GHCi> Last (Just 3) <> Last (Just 4)
Last {getLast = Just 4}
GHCi> Alt (Just 3) <> Alt (Just 4)
Alt {getAlt = Just 3}
GHCi> Dual (Alt (Just 3)) <> Dual (Alt (Just 4))
Dual {getDual = Alt {getAlt = Just 4}}
```

(By the way, `Alt` delegates `mempty` and `mappend` to the `Alternative` instance of `Maybe`, which is equivalent to what Alec suggests [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770703/why-does-mempty-evaluate-the-content-of-the-monoid#comment72657389_42770703).)